# The method of storing aws rds manual snapshot more than 100

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, snapshot

Currently, the number of my manual snapshot is almost 100. And aws allows us to store up to 100 manual snapshots.

But I don't want to remove this snapshot. I want to keep longer for restoring in the future.

I can't find proper way. I need your advice.
Here is my searching result.

1. dump with xtrabackup and keep dump data in aws s3

- Our data is bigger than 4 tb, we can't handle xtrabackup server about big data.
- so this method doesn't work well to us.

2. send to s3 button

- there is a button named "send to s3"
- but this button is not for restoring. As I know this is for data tools (like Athena...)
- can't restore after stored in s3

3. send to another account

- make a new account, send manual snapshot to theirs.
- I think this is a good way, but we need to make new account every 100, so I want to find a new way.

Is there any other method to store snapshot data?
I don't care any method if we restore data to db instance(clusters.. anyway)

FYI : We are using Aurora DB (MySql 5.7)

Answer (score 1):

You can **request an increase in the quota**.

Go to the **Service Quotas** management console and click **Request increase at account-level:**

[image: Service Quotas]

Comment: Thanks for helping. And how many can we increase? Is there any limit?

Comment: They might ask for a reason, but ask for what you think you'll need. You could also consider using the automated snapshot capabilities.